# Как сохранить геопозицию (локацию) пользователя в Telegram используя базу данных sqlite3 и python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite, telebot, геолокация

Это часть кода, в котором реализована возможность сохранения такой информации как username, телефон, имя, фамилия и номер пользователя, после того как пользователь отправляет свои контакты(номер) у меня все эти данные сохраняются в БД. Могу ли я таким образом сохранить в базу данных или может еще куда-то геопозицию (локацию) пользователя, после того как он отправил свою геопозицию? Возможно есть другой способ, кто знает поделитесь пожалуйста!

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["contact"])
def contact(message):
    with sq.connect("bot5.db") as con:
        cur = con.cursor()

        # cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS info1")
        cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info1(
            id TEXT,
            numbers TEXT,
            first_name TEXT,
            last_name TEXT,
            usersname TEXT
        )""")

        # cur.execute("""UPDATE info1 SET numbers = '+' """)
        con.commit()
        people_id = message.from_user.id
        cur.execute(f"SELECT id FROM info1 WHERE id = {people_id} ")
        data = cur.fetchone()
        if data is None:
            users_id = [message.from_user.id, 'Number: ' + message.contact.phone_number, 'Nickname: ' + message.from_user.first_name, message.from_user.last_name, 'Username: ''@' + message.from_user.username]
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO info1 VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", users_id)
            con.commit()
        else:
            chat_id = message.chat.id
            bot.send_message(chat_id, "Такой пользователь уже существует!")
```